# Find the length of tangent $x$.

Tags: geometry, circles

> Two circles $C_1$ and $C_2$ of radius $2$ and $3$ respectively touch each other as shown in the figure .If $AD$ and $BD$ are tangents then the length of $BD$ is

$a.)3\sqrt6\\
b.)5\sqrt6\\
\color{green}{c.)\dfrac{7\sqrt6}{3}}\\
d.)6\\$

[image]

[image]

I did a construction of $CE$

And with help of Pythagorus found $AE=2\sqrt{10}$

And with again pythagorus i applied

$10^2+x^2=(x+2\sqrt{10})^2\implies x=3 \sqrt{\dfrac52}$

But the book is giving option $c.$  what is the mistake ?

Comment: Looks like the book's answer is wrong.

Comment: I  found $\dfrac{3\sqrt{10}}2$, which is the same as you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin\angle{EAC} = \frac{R}{2r+R} \implies \angle{EAC} = 25.37$$

$$\tan\angle{DAB} = \frac{x}{2r+2R} \implies x = 4.74$$

You are right, there is a mistake in the book.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the second diagram, we have in right $\Delta ABD$ we have $$AD=\sqrt{x^2+10^2}=\sqrt{x^2+100}$$ Now, in right triangles $\Delta ABD$ & $\Delta AEC_{2}$, we have $$\sin \angle DAB=\sin \angle EAC_{2} \implies \frac{BD}{AD}=\frac{EC_{2}}{AC_{2}} \implies \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+100}}=\frac{3}{7}$$ $$49x^2-9x^2=900 \implies x=\sqrt{\frac{900}{40}}=\sqrt{\frac{45}{2}}=3\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}}$$

The result is obviously same as you have obtained hence, there is certainly some printing mistake in the options provided in your book.